# updating notification text every second with handler

Tags: java, android

i've a strange issue. i want to update the text of a notification every second so i wrote this code

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                batteryTemperature = getBatteryTemperature();

                    new Handler().postDelayed(this, 1000);

                }
            }, 1000);

       if(batteryTemperature != 0) {

builder.setContentText("BatteryLevel"+batteryTemperature);
} else {
builder.setContentText("The batteryTemperature value is 0");
}
```

With a Log i saw that in the Handler the batteryTemperature value is different from 0 but out of the Handler it return 0. Why? How can i set the correct value in the notification?

Answer (score 3):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    batteryTemperature = getBatteryTemperature();
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
 }, 1000);
```

Do not create a Handler every time the Runnable is called. You need to executed this snippet, every time the runnable is executed

```
  if(batteryTemperature != 0) {
   builder.setContentText("BatteryLevel"+batteryTemperature);
  } else {
    builder.setContentText("The batteryTemperature value is 0");
  }
```

Comment: you have to executed the if/else snippet every time the runnable is called

Answer (score 2):

Try this (UI thread safe):

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
{
    private final Handler   mHandler    = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                batteryTemperature = getBatteryTemperature();
                if (batteryTemperature != 0)
                {
                    builder.setContentText("BatteryLevel" + batteryTemperature);
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.setContentText("The batteryTemperature value is 0");
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you're asking: 1) how do I update my notification and 2) why is the value always 0?

Let me answer the second one first, try this code instead:

```
private MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
...
// get the ball rolling...
myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MyHandler.UPDATE, 1000);
...
private class MyHandler extends Handler {
    private int UPDATE = 0;

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case UPDATE:
                updateBatteryTemperatureNotification(getBatteryTemperature());
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MyHandler.UPDATE, 1000);
                break;
            case STOP:
                removeMessages(UPDATE);
                break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

Is it safe to assume you know how to update the `Notification` when you have the data correct?